# C# Unity the namespace '<global namespace>' already contains a definition for

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am studying access modifiers and I came across the following error in my code. Can someone explain to me and help me solve it?
Assets\Testes\Scripts\modificadoracesso.cs(40,7): error CS0101: The namespace '< global namespace >' already contains a definition for 'Felino'

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class modificadoracesso : MonoBehaviour
{

    Felino gatoFase1; // criar objeto
    Felino gatoFase2;
    Filha fi;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        gatoFase1 = new Felino (); //objeto
        gatoFase2 = new Felino ();
        fi = new Filha();

        //gatoFase1.nome = "mark";
        gatoFase1.ataque();
        gatoFase1.corPelo = "Preto";
        gatoFase1.forca = 100;

        //gatoFase2.nome = "Zuck";
        gatoFase2.corPelo = "Marrom";
        gatoFase2.ataque();

        fi.acessa();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}

class Felino : MonoBehaviour
{

    //Características = atributos
    //protected trabalha dentro a classe ou dentro de uma classe filha
    protected string nome;
    public string corPelo;
    public int forca;

    //Ações = métodos
    public void ataque()
    {
        print("Ataquei");
    }

}

class Filha : Felino
{
    public void acessa()
    {
        nome = "Gato";
    }
}
```

I've looked for some answers but so far nothing works

Comment: The global namespace part is because you don't have a namespace in your code.  I can't see why you have a duplicate `Felino` though.

Comment: i'm brazilian and i didn't understand the sentence "namespace" could it show me in a practical way?

Comment: what would be <global namespace>?

Comment: Please use english while writing code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless a class is in a namespace, the class it in the 'global namespace'.   Add a namespace around your classes.   I'm not saying this is the complete answer, but not using namespaces is a bad idea.   Namespaces usually start with the name of your solution and will be placed there automatically when you create a new class.

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace ToDyToScAnO // <-- This is a namespace
{
  public class modificadoracesso : MonoBehaviour
  {

    Felino gatoFase1; // criar objeto
    Felino gatoFase2;
    Filha fi;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        gatoFase1 = new Felino (); //objeto
        gatoFase2 = new Felino ();
        fi = new Filha();

        //gatoFase1.nome = "mark";
        gatoFase1.ataque();
        gatoFase1.corPelo = "Preto";
        gatoFase1.forca = 100;

        //gatoFase2.nome = "Zuck";
        gatoFase2.corPelo = "Marrom";
        gatoFase2.ataque();

        fi.acessa();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}

class Felino : MonoBehaviour
{

    //Características = atributos
    //protected trabalha dentro a classe ou dentro de uma classe filha
    protected string nome;
    public string corPelo;
    public int forca;

    //Ações = métodos
    public void ataque()
    {
        print("Ataquei");
    }

}

 class Filha : Felino
 {
    public void acessa()
    {
        nome = "Gato";
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This usually occurs when you **drag and drop** a script to **another folder**, while your text editor still has the script open. When you save the file in text editor, **the file is re-created in old location**, so you have a duplicate script for the moved script.

Answer (score 3):

It's only because you have another script in your project with this name!
Maybe you accidentally duplicate it or something.